# WPF XAML - Inherit Bursh from Parent to Fascilitate Icon Reuse

Tags: wpf, xaml, imagesource

I have the following structure in my WPF app:

App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DrawingImage x:Key="mycion">
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{WHAT DO I PUT HERE?}" Geometry="M8,8L56,8 56,13.375 8,13.375 8,8z M8,24L8,18.625 56,18.625 56,24 8,24z M8,34.625L8,29.375 56,29.375 56,34.625 8,34.625z M8,45.375L8,40 56,40 56,45.375 8,45.375z M8,56L8,50.625 56,50.625 56,56 8,56z" />
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Window1.xaml:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="33,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115">
    <!-- I want this image to be Red. -->
    <Image Height="25" Width="42" Source="{StaticResource mycion}"/>
</Button>

<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="33,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115">
    <!-- I want this image to be Green. -->
    <Image Height="25" Width="42" Source="{StaticResource mycion}"/>
</Button>
```

Question:

How do I allow for the ability to change Brush color (Red/Green in my example) of the resource (custom icon from a resource dictionary implemented as a `DrawingImage`) bound to a property that expects `ImageSource`?

Basically I want to somehow have the ability to have my icons defined in the ResourceDictionaries as Geometries, but with the ability to easily set those as values to properties expecting `ImageSource` *and the ability to change / set the Brush used to render that Geometry on the parent object or in the XAML of the window somehow (so it propagates down to the icon resource)*.

Note: that I used `Image` nested in a `Button` only as an example. The icon need not be set on an image necessarily, but more often as a value to a property on some other element that expects `ImageSource`.

I am also open to other possibilities - not just using `DrawingImage`, but I am relatively new to WPF so don't know how else it can be easily achieved, given that:

- My icons are represented as geometries
- I do need to be able to set the Brush on a per-UIElement basis (where icon is used)
- I do not want to set the icon as (part of) the content of the element - it's just too cumbersome and complicated (dealing with layout for a simple button - if you want to have both icon and text, etc.).

Any tips on the matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store geometry as a Resource as it is the worst part to repeat (DRY)

```
<Geometry x:Key="ico">M8,8L56,8 56,13.375 8,13.375 8,8z M8,24L8,18.625 56,18.625 56,24 8,24z M8,34.625L8,29.375 56,29.375 56,34.625 8,34.625z M8,45.375L8,40 56,40 56,45.375 8,45.375z M8,56L8,50.625 56,50.625 56,56 8,56z</Geometry>
```

and create a DrawingImage of each color (GeometryDrawing is separated from DrawingImage to make code shorter)

```
<GeometryDrawing x:Key="red"  Brush="Red" Geometry="{StaticResource ico}" />
<DrawingImage x:Key="redIcon" Drawing="{StaticResource red}"/>

<GeometryDrawing x:Key="green"  Brush="Green" Geometry="{StaticResource ico}" />
<DrawingImage x:Key="greenIcon" Drawing="{StaticResource green}"/>
```

usage

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115">
    <Image Height="25" Width="42" Source="{StaticResource redIcon}"/>
</Button>

<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115">
    <Image Height="25" Width="42" Source="{StaticResource greenIcon}"/>
</Button>
```

if a lot of colors are required, it is better to create a converter which will use geometry resource and return DrawingImage of requested color

---

example of converter which I'm talking about:

```
public class GeometryColorConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // getting geometry from App resources
        var g = (Geometry)value;

        // set Black as default color 
        string colorName = (string)parameter ?? "Black";

        // parsing color name
        var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(colorName);

        // creating Image
        return new DrawingImage
        {
            Drawing = new GeometryDrawing(new SolidColorBrush(color), null, g)
        };            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
<local:GeometryColorConverter x:Key="paint"/>

<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115">
    <Image Height="25" Width="42" 
        Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ico}, 
                         Converter={StaticResource paint}, 
                         ConverterParameter=Orange}"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes, I would certainly prefer to store only the geometry and rely on converter or converters. Can you please modify your answer to give a sample usage of converter then? Ideally, in pseudo-code I would want something like this (as I understood you, it should be possible with a converter): `<Button Image="{SomeConverter {StaticResource myicongeometry} mydesiredbrush}" />` But I am not sure how do I actually implement it, and what is the cost (in terms of CPU and memory of this approach - I plan to have 100s of elements like this).

Comment: @FitDev, i added an example. 100 elements will require 100 images. resource based approach is cheaper, but this way you can easily use any color without making a new resource

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's pretty much what I wanted. Though, I was asking about the cost of using such ValueConverters for 100s of icons/elements, in terms of CPU/memory?

Comment: Oh, and another thing... in your example of implementing `IValueConverter`, the icon is hard-coded, however it must be a parameter "read from" XAML. The whole point is that the converter should be icon-agnostic. Basically it takes in an icon (geometry), and a brush and outputs the DrawingImage

Comment: @FitDev, it is pretty fast and cheap in terms cpu/memory. my mistake with App.Resources["ico"], it should be `value` of course, fixed